# Tree structure with duplicate leafs in UITableView in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, data-structures, tree

I am in the middle of creating a menu with a `tableView` which ultimately leads to users entering a certain parameter and then outputs the results.

The menu consists of several pages and depending on what the user selects, it will give different user inputs. It is very similar to iPhone settings.

Right now, the way I model the menu is with a tree structure:

```
class Node {

    let value: Modules

    var parentNode: Node?
    var childenNode = [Node]()

    var childCount: Int {
        return childenNode.count
    }

    func appendNode(node: Node) {
        childenNode.append(node)
        node.parentNode = self
    }

    func isLeaveNode() -> Bool {
        return childenNode.isEmpty
    }

    init(module: Modules) {
        self.value = module
    }              
}
```

It is very simple and typical tree data structure. My problem is this, there can be duplicate nodes and means that the parent node will be overridden. For example, given a structure like this:

```
             [1] 
           /     \
       [2]         [3]
      /               \
   [4]                 [4]
```

If I model this tree with my code, it will look like this:

```
let node1 = Node(.1)
let node2 = Node(.2)
let node3 = Node(.3)
let node4 = Node(.4)

node1.appendNode(node2)
node1.appendNode(node3)

node2.appendNode(node4)
node3.appendNode(node4)
```

Since the appearance of node 4 is **NOT** unique, therefore the parent of `node4` will be overridden and the parent is now `node3`. Whereas, `node2` and `node3` should share the same leaf. How should I change my code so any given leaf node can have more than one parent?

Additional information: the `Modules` is an `enum`. This problem can easily be solved by just creating more `enum` members but is there other way of solving the problem?

Any suggestions are welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using an enum for Modules?

Comment: yes I am. The modules are enum

Comment: You are asking: "How should I change my code so my leaf nodes can have different parents?" but the only nodes that have the same parents are node2, and node3.  Do you not want node2 and node3 to share a parent? Why wouldn't want this?

Comment: Node 4 needs to have more than one parent. Currently, Node 4 can only have one parent. I do want node2 and node3 to have the same parent. What I want is for node to have more than one parent without creating more enum cases.

Comment: Let me know if my answer doesn't solve your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can change

`var parentNode: Node?` to `var parentNodes: [Node?]`

```
func appendNode(node: Node) {
    childenNode.append(node)
    node.parentNodes.append(self)
}
```

However, this is bad practice.  You will no longer have a tree, but a graph.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `Modules` is an enumeration and therefore a value. If `Modules` truly has value semantics, then all you need to do create two distinct `Node(.4)`. Each has a separate parent. Do not keep `node4` variables around and instead trust your tree structure and navigate around in it with confidence.

```
node2.appendNode(Node(.4))
node3.appendNode(Node(.4))
```

You will need to rethink our class and how to construct the tree more intuitively. Maybe something along the lines of

```
init(_ module: Module, children: [Node] = [Node]()) {
  self.value = module
  self.children = children
  foreach child in self.children {
    child.parent = self
  }
}
```

Now you can initialize your tree like this.

```
let root =
      Node(.1, children:
      [
        Node(.2, children: [Node(.4)]),
        Node(.3, children: [Node(.4)])
      ])
```

Comment: Yes, one way to solve this would be having two distinct `Node(.4)`, but they would mean my `enum` structure will be flooded with these new enum members, is there another way to achieve this without having to create new instances?

Comment: We don't have enough information to solve this. I am not sure what the problem is. Why would there be a flood of enumeration cases? There would not be any more than the .1, .2, .3, and .4 before. If the behavior of two nodes with the same Module value is different depending on their parent, then you will need to add that information to the Node's state and logic somehow but it doesn't affect the structure (as far as we can tell).

Comment: @BrendonCheung, I'm pretty sure my answer satisfies your question.  Can you let me know if it doesn't?

Comment: @PriceRingo  "Why would there be a flood of enumeration cases?", if we use the case above, then there would be two `node[.4]` which represents the same thing. The problem here is (and sorry if that is not properly defined, I will update the post) I need `node[.4]` to have both `node[.2]` and `node[.3]` as parents. The code that I have right now cannot achieve that because if i append `node2` with `node4` and then append `node3` with `node4`, the `node2` as parent will be overridden.

Comment: @ScottyBlades Thanks for your help, is there another without using an array? The reason for this is that when the user reaches the user input page, I need to know the path the user took and if I have an array of parents, I wouldn't know what the user has selected. thanks

Comment: @BrendonCheung The order that the parents would be in the array would tell you the order that they were selected, but it definitely sounds like I need to hear more about exactly what you are trying to do for the user. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something.